# Should the installed entry in the registry be in the Microsoft folder?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

When adding a shortcut to an installer created with Wix, according to [How To: Create a Shortcut on the Start Menu](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html), you need to add a registry value with like this:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

Should that value really be inside of `Software\Microsoft`? In many cases in the Microsoft world I'm seeing the vendor used as the scope so I'm wondering if it shouldn't really be `Software\MyVendorName\MyApplicationName`.

Comment: That might be an remnant from the early days when WiX was a Microsoft project. For another excellent tutorial on WiX see [WiXTutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/) . They are placing the keys the way you would do it (`Software\MyVendorName\MyApplicationName`)

Comment: Hi pupeno. I added a couple of more details that could conceivably be of importance for you. MSI is very complicated in its details, but I don't think this particular issue will affect you (COM registration). Apologies for complicating things - perhaps unnecessarily - but I add more details to make the answer more generally applicable for others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely write to my own location as indicated by others:

- `HKCU\Software\MyVendorName\MyApplicationName`
- `HKLM\Software\MyVendorName\MyApplicationName`

Ideally your application should not write anywhere else in the registry - except beneath these two parent locations. You "own" these two registry locations - and nowhere else. You shouldn't write anywhere else - and certainly not under the Microsoft key. I believe that is a "generic sample".

The exception is when you need to **register certain files** (or components) - for example **COM files** whose registration go into `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`. These per machine and per-user locations are merged to produce `HKCR` (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`). COM registration can also be isolated, in which case you use manifest files - then the registry is not involved at all. WiX features special COM-related elements that will populate the registry for you via standard MSI mechanisms - the `heat.exe` tool for harvesting COM registration (among other things) will auto-generate these elements for you and your compiled MSI will have [several MSI tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) keeping the COM registration information (`ProgId`, `Class`, `TypeLib`, etc...).

**UPDATE**: Not to compliate things too much, but an MSI can be installed per-user or per-machine based on the values of [ALLUSERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MSIINSTALLPERUSER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007(v=vs.85).aspx) properties. If you have populated the proper COM tables in the MSI the COM server will be registered per-machine or per-user accordingly.

And there are other cases where installation processes make changes elsewhere in the registry if you install your package. For example when you install **drivers**, **plug-ins**, **fonts**, **COM+**, **COM Interop**, **file extensions**, etc... Your registration in these cases should generally go through APIs that take care of registering your components and you should not poke around i the registry yourself in most cases. A lot of such registration is handled by MSI if you do it right - or built-in constructs in third party tools used to make MSI files.

Comment: Thank you. I doubt it'll be accepted because Wix3 is no longer under active development, but I sent a pull request to modify Wix's documentation on this matter: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/463